# (iOS) Can we have multiple APNs files for the same app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are in the process of migrating from one CCM to another.  I need to generate a new .p8 file so our new CCM can send push notifications to our iOS app via APNS.  If I do this, can our old CCM still send pushes with the old .p8 as long as we don't revoke it in AppStoreConnect?

The option to add a new .p8 exists, but I want to verify before doing it.

Comment: If you don't revoke the old one then it isn't revoked...

Comment: @Paulw11 I know it seems obvious I just get petrified at the thought of ruining our CCM service.  Thanks!

Comment: You can have multiple certificates because you need to be able to issue a new one and install it before your old one expires.